# Prettier format java in markdown code block

Tags: java, markdown, prettier

````
```java
class AppClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
NewClass newClass = new NewClass();
// Perform operations on newClass
}
}
```
````

How do you format java code within markdown?

Script:  `prettier --write **/*.{md}`

It works pretty well for web languages (js,jsx, html....) in markdown.

I tried installing `prettier-plugin-java` also doesn't help inside markdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prettier --write ./java.md --plugin="./node_modules/prettier-plugin-java"
```

This amazingly works, may work with other languages too **within markdown**, Here is the list of plugins https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html have only tried **java** community plugin.

Do try other language formatting support in markdown if interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is a another equivalent way, you can specify the prettier plugin in its configuration file. For example, `.prettierrc` like this:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-java"]
}
```